# Storing private keys using DSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, digital-signature

I'm trying to use the DSACryptoServiceProvider class with C# to create two DLLs: one will have the ability to verify and **create** digital signatures, the other will just be able to verify. Basically, I'm trying to create a private/public key pair and save they keys accordingly (to a file).

I'm running into problems when using ExportParameters(). When I attempt to export the key containing the private information (using serialize), the private information is automatically nulled out.

Is there a better way to store the keys?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show us *how* you are exporting thos parameters? It should be possible to save priv+pub and pub-only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider.exportparameters(VS.80).aspx

I think what you want to do is:

```
ExportParameters(true)
```

The 'true' means it'll export the private parts