# How to store the keys generated by DSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, digital-signature

As explained [in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider.exportparameters(VS.80).aspx), it is possible to generate new public/private keys by calling the method `DSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters`. The result of this method is of type `DSAParameters`.

What is the de facto standard on dealing with these keys? Should I generate new keys for each transaction or should I generate keys once, store them and reuse them ad eternum?

If it's better to keep them, how do I store these keys?

**EDIT:**

There's a previous [homonymous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603801/storing-private-keys-using-dsacryptoserviceprovider) but the accepted answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I generate new keys for each transaction or should I generate keys once

Depends entirely on the situation/application.

> how do I store these keys

DsaParameters is Serializable so you can read/write it as XML (SoapFormatter).

And the DSACryptoServiceProvider class itself has ToXml/FromXml members. Iirc this can also be used to store/restore the keys.